# drop file js get main id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

My HTML page

```
<div id="myID" class="front" onMouseOver="oneffect(); ondragover="dragover(this);" ondragleave="dragleave(this);">
    <img class="withUpload" src="../img/withUpload.png"/>
    <span class="nbreResult">20</span>
    <span>
         <h1>Title</h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

My listener JS

```
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);
    e.preventDefault();
    getFile(e.dataTransfer, e.target.id)
},false);
```

When I drop a file on my div, I wanna get the ID, but I just realised that if the user drop his file on a children (title, img, span), then I won't get any ID, because they don't have one. So the users have to drop on "free zone". How can I do to get my DIV ID everywhere in the DIV and not just on "free zone". 
    [image: Example]

You can see [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4wC9/3/) as well
Hope I m clear!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use jQuery to find the parent DIV and it's ID easily.

Not tested but this ought to work.

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
    var id = $(e.target).parents('div.front').attr('id');
    alert(id);
    e.preventDefault();
    getFile(e.dataTransfer, e.target.id)
},false);
```

Comment: @WhitneyR. Please can you setup a jsfiddle.net so we can help and 'fiddle' ~?!

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding event Listener to window, add it to div `myID`

`document.getElementByID("myID").addEventListener(....,function(){...........},...);`

Comment: That would be great, but I've a random number of div MyID and the ID can change

Comment: what do you mean by random number of div MyID??

Comment: boxes like my image arrive in my page from a DB and so I can have one box or several. Then I can't create Listener for each box. By box I mean my div

Comment: its gud.. why can't you create? id is unique.. how will you set it for all? then place common class name then use getElementsByClassName()[i] and add listener using loop.. its the easy way. not difficult

Comment: Is my answer helpful or not?